# Add Values in textbox with comma seperation

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an integer called `Id`, this id gets a different value (ex. 101) on each button click. Whenever the button is clicked, I want to concatenate these values into a `textbox1` separated by commas:  `101,102,103`

Comment: "id is getting on button click 101". This is not understandable. Show your exiting code please and clarify your question.

Comment: I didn't understand much, but I assume that you want comma separated values in textbox, You try something like txt1.text = txt1.text & id & ","

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what you mean. This should work like you expect:

```
public void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text)
    {
       textBox.Text = Id;
    }
    else 
    {
       textBox.Text += "," + Id;
    }
}
```